# Vuex store value not set in mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have had problems where I am getting a null value from my store... sometimes, and only on some values.  If anyone could point me in the right direction and explain why it is wrong... I would be really grateful.  So here is the deal my `store.getters.getApiKey` is sometimes `""` and sometimes not.
So... in the component vue below, it is not null on the first reference

`{{this.$store.getters.getApiKey}}`

and then within the mounted section, `store.getters.getHostUrl` is set, but `store.getters.getApiKey` keeps returning `""`.

Here are the details:
the Component.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="countryCodes">
    <p>ApiKey :  {{this.$store.getters.getApiKey}}</p>
    <p>CountryCode Data is {{ page }}</p>
    <div class="CountryCodes">
      <tr v-for="ccdata in content_list" v-bind:key="ccdata.guid">
        <td>{{ ccdata.guid }}</td>
        <td>{{ ccdata.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ ccdata.code }}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

import axios from "axios";
import store from "@/store";

export default {
  name: 'CountryCodes',
  data () {
    return {
      page: "",
      content_list: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   axios({ method: "GET", "url": store.getters.getHostUrl + " 
"/api/"+store.getters.getApiKey+"/countryCodes" }).then(result => {
      this.page = result.data.page;
      this.content_list = result.data.contents;
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

Then my store (store.js) looks like this...

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        apiKey: "",
        hostUrl:""
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_APIKEY(state, value) { state.apiKey = value;   },
        SET_HOST_URL(state, value) {state.hostUrl = value; }
    },
    getters: {
        getApiKey(state) {  return state.apiKey; },
        getHostUrl(state) {  return state.hostUrl; }
    }
})
```

finally in my main.js  I commit the data to the store... :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index.js'
import store from './store.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  store,
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$route.query)
    store.commit('SET_APIKEY',  this.$route.query.api)
    store.commit("SET_HOST_URL", location.origin.toString())
  }
})
```

I have the same problem when trying to build a http service, where the store is null for the apikey. What magic am I missing?

Comment: Let me add a detail.. I think this is a timing issue.  The data is displayed on my first route into the app.  If I navigate to a different route, and then back, the values will be correctly set.  Maybe I need to add a watch?

Comment: I initialise my store in `beforeCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `mounted` hook of child component is called before the `mounted` of parent component.

[image: parent-child-lifecycle]

> From [Vue Parent and Child lifecycle hooks](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f)

If you try to `console.log` on both `mounted` hook you will see the order of execution (but I'm still not sure why your `store.getters.getHostUrl` is set).

So you need a watcher to run your code after your store has value.

Example code:

```js
...
  computed: { // or use another getters
    url () {
      if (!store.getters.getHostUrl || !store.getters.getApiKey) return
      return `${store.getters.getHostUrl}/api/${store.getters.getApiKey}/countryCodes`
    }
  },
  watch: {
    url (value) {
      ...
    }
  }
...
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-firefly-igerg)

Comment: Thank you !  I did see the other state diagram that detail the state of the component... but I did not see this one on component to component flow.  Very helpful...  I did put a watch in and that worked... I am also looking into when I see those values in which states!  As the article you pointed at says "unintuitive order that these hooks will fire"!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So.... there were two ways of solving this..... thank you to both comments.

1. Switch my mounted in the main.js to created-  the diagram above explains why... as well as the nice article.
2. add "await store.getters.getApiKey"